# Azure & Crm Integration using TwoWay

Tags: azure, office365, dynamics-crm-online

I am registering a New Service Endpoint for a "TwoWay" listener and the PluginRegistrationTool is throwing an error: `Invalid Namespace`

Note that I have created and configured the Namespace using GUI and Powershell cmdlet however both returning same error.

Tried to see the exact name using this command: `Get-AzureSBNamespace`
I am using a Trial version so this could has some limitations?

Comment: What did `Get-AzureSBNamespace` return? Trial or not should not matter.

Comment: It returns the collection of Namespaces.